# Calling View() inside a controller doesn't execute the ActionResult code immediately

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(...)
{
    ActionResult result = View("MyView", new MyModel());

    var fruit = TempData["Fruit"];
    // Do something with the fruit

    return result;
}
```

and this MyView.cshtml

```
@model MyModel
@{ 
    TempData["Fruit"] = "Mango";
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in the View where `TempData["Fruit"]` is set, it isn't called before the "`return result`" in the Action. The `Razor` rendering seems to be delayed.

How can I force the View to be rendered on return from the `result = View(..)` call?

Note: Don't worry about this simplistic example. We have a real use case where a solution to this would really be needed but I didn't want to burden the question any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View isn't rendered until after the Action is complete. You can call result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext) to force the early execution of the ActionResult inside the action like this:

```
    ActionResult result = View("Details", new PageModel(page));
    result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
```

But you will then have a problem because the ActionResult will be executed *again* when the action returns the result, so you will have to cancel that second execution.

You can do this like so:

```
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (cancelTheResult)
        {
            filterContext.Cancel = true;
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

This all does seem like a bit of a hack, but in some scenarios it seems necessary. For instance if a child action needs to tell the top level action to carry out a redirect, we won't know the redirect is required until the child action completes, but the child action won't be completed until too late. This is the only workaround I've been able to find.